# How to execute HTML code from ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm implementing MyPos payment gateway to accept debit card purchases. Their SDK is working in a weird manner. When I start the payment process, the SDK tries to echo HTML code with a form which will auto submit itself to their checkout page. This shouldn't be a problem if I submit my order page with the normal form submit, but I'm using ajax from my order page. I'm handling all other payment methods through ajax calls to my server, so I'd like to be consistent and use ajax here too.

So basically:

1. From my order page i press "pay with card" button.
2. Javascript will make ajax call to my server with order details, and will set up a purchase with MyPos sdk.
3. MyPos sdk echoes a HTML (but I'm capturing it with output buffer) which looks as following

```
<body onload="document.ipcForm.submit();">
<form id="ipcForm" name="ipcForm" action="https://www.mypos.eu/vmp/checkout-test" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="IPCmethod" value="IPCPurchase">
<input type="hidden" name="IPCVersion" value="1.4">
<input type="hidden" name="IPCLanguage" value="it">
<input type="hidden" name="SID" value="000000000000010">
<input type="hidden" name="WalletNumber" value="61938166610">
<input type="hidden" name="KeyIndex" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="Source" value="SDK_PHP_1.2.1">
<input type="hidden" name="Currency" value="EUR">
<input type="hidden" name="Amount" value="5.26">
<input type="hidden" name="OrderID" value="46057">
<input type="hidden" name="URL_OK" value="http://website.test/api/private/mypos/success-redirect">
<input type="hidden" name="URL_Cancel" value="http://website.test/api/private/mypos/cancel-redirect">
<input type="hidden" name="URL_Notify" value="http://website.test/api/private/mypos/ipc-notify">
<input type="hidden" name="Note" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="customeremail" value="testuser24@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="customerphone" value="3333333333">
<input type="hidden" name="customerfirstnames" value="Test">
<input type="hidden" name="customerfamilyname" value="User">
<input type="hidden" name="customercountry" value="ITA">
<input type="hidden" name="customercity" value="Arco">
<input type="hidden" name="customerzipcode" value="38062">
<input type="hidden" name="customeraddress" value="Via Fiori 12">
<input type="hidden" name="CartItems" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="Article_1" value="CRONO-Ex 1kg">
<input type="hidden" name="Quantity_1" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="Price_1" value="5.26">
<input type="hidden" name="Amount_1" value="5.26">
<input type="hidden" name="Currency_1" value="EUR">
<input type="hidden" name="CardTokenRequest" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="PaymentParametersRequired" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="PaymentMethod" value="3">
<input type="hidden" name="Signature" value="jq7OSRfkJmyt22rquIDoxK0QB1GBFug4eUcGYyyKg08bY+d036bgJ/R49iq9L8ZMB+Sz8VBDb/QsqLtRLqIbaP2e7j1sYRaoZZDeK+E3gRuDp/yJofVjPWjK8Q1ZbaokoM9ETaBZI+6oUjUEIES9nqfMYFgH0tk3axDcHkZ8HKg=">
</form>
</body>
```

Technically i should echo this to a page, and it will auto submit to their website. But instead I'm capturing this with output buffer, and send it back to javascript with JSON response.

Now how can I execute this HTML and make it do it's job? (eg. auto submitting itself to that post action URL)

Comment: Why the de-tour JS -> PHP -> JS -> yet another server? Why don't you send the request directly to _"yet another server"_?

Comment: [Minimal Reproducable Example Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please share more details. What do you mean by "execute this HTML"? How is this related to PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read the Action URL from the response separately and then serialize the form and make a new Ajax call again.

```
var myForm = $(response).find("#ipcForm");
var url = myForm.attr('action'); //get submit url [replace url here if desired]

$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: url,
     data: form.serialize(), // serializes form input
     success: function(data){
         console.log(data);
     }
});
```

Comment: I went this way, I guess it's the smartest way to do it in my situation.